# How to group a json object based on the equal key values using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following json object in javascript:

```
employeeRecords = [
    {
    "empID" : "7002",
    "company" : "Google",
    "group" : "Chrome",
    "id" : "D-2005",
    "city" : "New York",
    "date" : "2018-05-01"
    },
    {
    "empID" : "9002",
    "company" : "Apple",
    "group" : "iPhone",
    "id" : "D-2014",
    "city" : "Singapore"
    "date": "2019-07-15"
    },
    {
    "empID" : "7002",
    "company" : "Google",
    "group" : "Android",
    "id" : "H-2007",
    "city" : "London"
    "date": "2018-05-01"
    },
    {
    "empID" : "7002"
    "company" : "Google",
    "group" : "Android",
    "id" : "K-2007",
    "city" : "London"
    "date": "2019-06-18"
    },
    {
    "empID" : "9002",
    "company" : "Apple",
    "group" : "Laptop",
    "id" : "N-2012",
    "city" : "Japan"
    "date": "2019-07-15"
    }
]
```

The requirement is to group this json object, if the empID, company and the date is equal. If those key values are equal then the group field should be concatenated. I need to get this using JavaScript.

So the result should be like the following:

```
employeeRecords = [
    {
    "empID" : "7002",
    "company" : "Google",
    "group" : "Chrome-Android",
    "id" : "D-2005",
    "city" : "New York",
    "date" : "2018-05-01"
    },
    {
    "empID" : "9002",
    "company" : "Apple",
    "group" : "iPhone-Laptop",
    "id" : "D-2014",
    "city" : "Singapore"
    "date": "2019-07-15"
    },
    {
    "empID" : "7002"
    "company" : "Google",
    "group" : "Android",
    "id" : "K-2007",
    "city" : "London"
    "date": "2019-06-18"
    }
]
```

Any help to achieve this in JavaScript please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the difference beween this two jsons? I couldn' t find any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution that comes to my mind is to add an element to a new list according to a control while traversing all the elements with the Array.prototype.forEach method.

```
const fixedRecords = [];
employeeRecords.forEach(record => {
  let index = fixedRecords.findIndex(fr => fr.empID === record.empID && fr.date === record.date && fr.company === record.company)
  if(index !== -1) {
    fixedRecords[index] = {
       ...fixedRecords[index],
       group: fixedRecords[index].group + '-' + record.group 
    }
  }else {
    fixedRecords.push(record);
  }
})
```

This method will work. However, consider this; The findIndex function running for each list element means that this list will run for the number of elements for each element count (n * n). Therefore, if your list is large, it will not be very performant.

Answer (score 0):

This uses `reduce()` and a JS object to compute the groups and will run in `O(n)` which is (at least for large arrays) considerably quicker than an implementation with `includes()`, `find()` or other nested loop approaches which take `O(n²)`.

> Just a note: I am not sure why you would want `id` and `city` in the output as this is meaningless information as this is the information for the first employee of a group and may or may not be true for all employees in that group, hence it's useless information that could potentially be confusing as it looks like a legitimate employee.
>
> ```js
> const employeeRecords = [
>   {
>     empID: "7002",
>     company: "Google",
>     group: "Chrome",
>     id: "D-2005",
>     city: "New York",
>     date: "2018-05-01",
>   },
>   {
>     empID: "9002",
>     company: "Apple",
>     group: "iPhone",
>     id: "D-2014",
>     city: "Singapore",
>     date: "2019-07-15",
>   },
>   {
>     empID: "7002",
>     company: "Google",
>     group: "Android",
>     id: "H-2007",
>     city: "London",
>     date: "2018-05-01",
>   },
>   {
>     empID: "7002",
>     company: "Google",
>     group: "Android",
>     id: "K-2007",
>     city: "London",
>     date: "2019-06-18",
>   },
>   {
>     empID: "9002",
>     company: "Apple",
>     group: "Laptop",
>     id: "N-2012",
>     city: "Japan",
>     date: "2019-07-15",
>   },
> ];
>
> const resultObj = employeeRecords.reduce((acc, emp) => {
>   // concatenate the key (all criteria together build the key)
>   const key = `${emp.empID}-${emp.company}-${emp.date}`;
>   // if we already have a value with that key, add the group of the current employee
>   if(acc.hasOwnProperty(key)) acc[key].group += `-${emp.group}`;
>   // if we don't have a value with that key add that employee
>   else acc[key] = emp;
>   return acc;
> }, {});
>
> const result = Object.values(resultObj);
> console.log(result);
> ```